Check for continuity and uniform continuity of the given piecewise function
The function is
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
1+e^x,  & \text{if } x < 0 \\
2+\arctan x,  & \text{if } x \geq 0
\end{cases}$$
Continuity:
On the interval $(-\infty, 0)$, $f(x)=1+e^x$ is an elementary function and thus continuous.
On the interval $[0, +\infty)$, $f(x) = 2 + \arctan x$ is also an elementary function and is continuous.
Thus the function is continuous on $(-\infty, x) \cup [0, +\infty)$, it remains to check if it is continuous at $x=0$. Considering the left and the right limits, we have
$$\lim\limits_{x \uparrow 0} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \uparrow 0} 1 + e^x=2=\lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0} (2 + \arctan x)=\lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0} f(x)$$
and thus $f(x)$ is continous at $x=0$
Uniform continuity:
Here I'll use the following criteria:

If $f$ is continuous on $[a, +\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = L \in \mathbb R$ (i.e. L is a finite number), then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, +\infty)$. (The analogous statement holds for $(-\infty, a]$).

$1+e^x$ is continous on $(-\infty, 0]$ (as an elementary function) and $\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} 1 + e^x = 1$, and therefore by the above criteria it is also uniformly continuous on $(-\infty, 0]$ and all its subsets, in particular $(-\infty, 0)$.
$2+\arctan x$ is continuous on $[0, +\infty)$ (as an elementary function) and $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} (2 + \arctan x) = 2 + \frac{\pi}{2}$, so by the above criteria it is also uniformly continuous on $[0, +\infty)$.
We get that $f(x)$ is uniformly continous on its whole domain $(-\infty, 0] \cup [0, +\infty)$.
Is this reasoning alright? I'm curious if there's a better\right way to do it

Yes, you did it right. Also there is no need to check continuity at $0$, $f(x)$ is $1+e^x$ on $(-\infty, 0]$ and $2+\arctan(x)$ on $[0, \infty)$, both are closed sets. So its continuous on their union

@Jakobian oh you mean because both pieces have the same value for $x=0$, so I should've just said that? because actually $f(x)$ is $1+e^x$ for $x<0$, and thus $(-\infty, 0)$ is open, that's why I thought I still need to do it

@Jakobian I'd need to check if it's continuous at $0$ if it happened that the values didn't coincide for both pieces of the function right?

If $X$ is a union of finite amount of closed sets $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ and your function $f$ is continuous on $A_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$, then $f$ is continuous on $X$. This is just a standard fact from topology called gluing lemma.

@Jakobian I see, thanks!

It is simple to show the direct way
$$\begin{align}&  x>0,  \ \quad \delta >0: \\ 
&\left| e^{-(x+\delta )}-e^{-x}\right| =\left| e^{-x} \left(e^{-\delta }-1\right)\right| <\left| 1-e^{-\delta }\right| =\delta  \left| \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n \delta ^n}{(n+1)!}\right| <\delta \quad
\\&
\left| \tan ^{-1}(x+\delta )-\tan ^{-1}(x)\right| =\left| \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\delta }{x^2+\delta  x+1}\right)\right| <\delta, \quad x>0, \ \delta+x>0
\end{align}$$
